No Ranking Functions in Spotfire
May I know how to make the ranking functions in spotfire available? I do not know why, I tried searching it in web but there is no solution for it.
I only do have

Conversion functions
Date and Time functions
Math functions
Operators
Statistical Functions
Text Functions

My Spotfire version is 12.3.0.91

It is not about your Spotfire version, it is about your data source.
Some functions are not available if your data comes from e.g. a database source.
You need to check the Spotfire documentation for your data source.
